# Injectivity of divisible locally compact abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, topological-groups, abelian-categories, locally-compact-groups

Are divisible locally compact abelian groups injective as objects of the quasi-abelian category of locally compact abelian groups ? At the very least, if $D$ is a divisible locally compact abelian group then will the functor $Hom_{cont}(-, D): LocCompAb^{op} \to Ab$ preserve monomorphisms ?

Comment: Note that "divisible" can have several meanings: (a) for every $n\ge 1$, $x\mapsto nx$ is surjective [i.e., the underlying group is divisible] (b) for every $n\ge 1$, the map $x\mapsto nx$ is a quotient map. Even for torsion-free locally compact abelian groups, (b) is strictly stronger than (a).